# Cant declare an instance with type parameter that is one layer off the constraint of the type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have

```
 class A<T> where T:DataTable{}
```

and

```
 class B:TypedTableBase<S>{}
```

System.Data.TypedTableBase extends DataTable, but I can't declare

```
 private A<B> a;
```

Compiler complains no implicit conversion exists between B and DataTable, but B extends TypedTableBase which extends DataTable.

I don't understand this, can someone explain? Is there a way to accomplish what I want? I.e., declare private A a;
Can I create an implicit conversion operator that just returns (DataTable)b ?

EDIT - SHORT CODE EXAMPLE

with

```
public partial class NOTIFICATION_RECORDDataTable : global::System.Data.TypedTableBase<NOTIFICATION_RECORDRow> { ... }
```

and

```
public class CachedSortableDataSource<T>:ICachedSortableDataSource where T:DataTable     {...}
```

A is CachedSortableDataSource; B is NOTIFICATION_RECORDDataTable.

```
private void InitializeSortableDataGrid()
{
//following line wont compile:
CachedSortableDataSource<Data.FD.NOTIFICATION_RECORDDataTable> ds = new CachedSortableDataSource<FD.DataAccess.FD.NOTIFICATION_RECORDDataTable>();

ds.Adapter = new Data.FDTableAdapters.NOTIFICATION_RECORDTableAdapter();
ds.Cache("220");
sortableDataGrid1.CachedSortableData = ds;
}
```

EDIT - CANT DECLARE CLASS THAT EXTENDS TYPEDTABLEBASE

There might be more to the story because in the declaration for

```
NOTIFICATIONRECORDDataTable : global::System.Data.TypedTableBase<NOTIFICATION_RECORDRow>
```

The tool tip says:

This type is used as a base class for typed-System.Data.DataTable object generation by Visual Studio and the XSD.exe .NET Framework tool, and is not intended to be used directly from your code.

And indeed I cant declare in my code file

```
 public class B:System.Data.TypedTableBase<DataRow> {}
```

EDIT - RESOLVED

I couldnt declare becuase TypedTableBase is in the system.data.datasetextensions assembly.

All is good now. 
Thanks to all!

Comment: Works for me, using `B:TypedTableBase<DataRow>` instead as we don't know what `S` is meant to be. Please give a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - that'll make it much easier to find out what's wrong. (It doesn't need to do anything - just be complete and ready to compile.)

Comment: Edit Added short example

Comment: It's not a *complete* example by any means though. We don't have the declaration for `NOTIFICATION_RECORDROW`, for example. What I want is a single block of code that I can copy into a file, and compile.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your type arguments don't match. Split the line up and it becomes more obvious:

```
CachedSortableDataSource<Data.FD.NOTIFICATION_RECORDDataTable> ds = new 
   CachedSortableDataSource<FD.DataAccess.FD.NOTIFICATION_RECORDDataTable>();
```

`Data.FD.NOTIFICATION_RECORDDataTable` isn't the same type as `FD.DataAccess.FD.NOTIFICATION_RECORDDataTable`.

If you make it:

```
CachedSortableDataSource<Data.FD.NOTIFICATION_RECORDDataTable> ds = new 
   CachedSortableDataSource<Data.FD.NOTIFICATION_RECORDDataTable>();
```

(Or maybe using `FD.DataAccess.FD.NOTIFICATION_RECORDDataTable` - we don't know which you meant) then it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since TypedTableBase is generic, when you use it, you have to specify the actual datatype
as in

```
public class A<T> where T:DataTable
   {

   }

    public class B :TypedTableBase<DataRow>
    {
    }

    class MyClass
    {
         A<B> asdf = new A<B>();
    }
```

Comment: This isnt the issue. When I declare A<B>, B here is declared with the type parameter, so I dont need to pass a type argument

Comment: The asdf variable in MyClass wont compile with error i gave above

Comment: So the class TypedTableBase is once declared as generic in .Net and when you use it (including inheritance in ur case), you have to specify the actual type :(

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt declare

```
 class B:TypedTableBase<DataRow>{ }
```

because I was missing  assembly System.Data.DataSetExtensions

All is good now - It wasnt an indirect inheritance problem.

Thanks to all.